# Apply rule based grouping on Java enum

Tags: java, enums, overriding, grouping, xstream

*(this question does not require knowledge of XStream as such)*

**Below is the request XML structure** which is unmarshalled to Root java bean using XStream -

```
<Root>
  <Entity>
     <Action>...</Action>
     <Type>...</Type>
     <Data>...</Data>
  </Entity>
</Root>
```

Since **Data** node is polymorphic it can map to either of the beans i.e. **DataABC, DataPQR, DataXYZ** and so on :

```
<Data>
   <A>aaa</A>
   <B>bbb</B>
   <C>ccc</C>
 </Data>
or
 <Data>
   <P>ppp</P>
   <Q>qqq</Q>
   <R>rrr</R>
 </Data>
or
 <Data>
   <X>xxx</X>
   <Y>yyy</Y>
   <Z>zzz</Z>
 </Data>
```

> xstream helps in umarshaling the bean like :
>
> Root root = xstream.fromXML(rootXML)

There is a **Configurer interface** which helps in configure XStream object by mapping xml tags of a section with actual pojo bean :

```
interface Configurer<T> {
    public void configure(T t);
}

enum ConfigurersLib implements Configurer<XStream> {
    ROOT("Root", Root.class),
    ENTITY("Entity", Entity.class),
    TYPE("Type", Type.class),
    ACTION("Action", Action.class),
    // polymorphic data tag configurers
    DATA_ABC("Data", DataABC.class),
    DATA_PQR("Data", DataPQR.class),
    DATA_XYZ("Data", DataXYZ.class),
    ;

   @Override
   public void configure(XStream xs){
     xs.alias(this.xmlTag, this.classType);
   }
   //constructor
   private ConfigurersLib(String tag, Class classType){
    this.xmlTag = tag;
    this.classType = classType;
   }
   ...
}
```

For a given request **Type** - I can group some configurers to make a chain-of-responsibility, where one chain is an EnumSet :

> if Type = ABC  then  invoke chain -- {ROOT, ENTITY, ACTION, TYPE, DATA_ABC}
>
> if Type = PQR  then  invoke chain -- {ROOT, ENTITY, ACTION, TYPE, DATA_PQR}
>
> if Type = XYZ  then  invoke chain -- {ROOT, ENTITY, ACTION, TYPE, DATA_XYZ}

Above illustration is simpler but unfortunately these configurers are large in number (50-100+) so there is possibility of missing some Configurer enum elements while creating such groups. This might reduce some clarity too.

**Question**
What is the best WAY (pattern/trick/standards) to make sure -

1. How to define completeness (Configurer set is complete iff we have all tags covered for a given incoming request)
2. How to make grouping easily be overridable (For some special case we may want to use PQR instead of ABC. Or default to XYZ etc)